# What does this sign exactly mean? |=

Tags: java, android, bit-manipulation, flags

|=

I'm curious to learn about this operator,
I've seen this notation used while setting flags in Java.

for example:

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

1. Does it perform some kind of bit manipulation?
2. What does this mark exactly do?
3. Are there any other well known signs similar to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is equivalent to

```
notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

where `|` is bitwise OR operator which OR the two variables bit-by-bit.

It is well known by itself. There are also `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, `&=`, `^=`.

Comment: Edited. Hope there is enough keywords for web surfing.

Comment: It is bitwise or logical, depending on the operand types.

Answer (score 3):

This syntax is also available in C/C++ and other languages.  It is a bitwise OR and the same as:

```
notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

and similar to other operators like addition, subtraction, etc.  For example:

```
i += 5;
```

is the same as:

```
i = i + 5;
```

Answer (score 3):

> (1) Does it perform some kind of bit manipulation?

If you use `|` with numeric operands then yes, it will be [bitwise](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) OR, if you use it on boolean operands it will be logical (non-short-circuit) OR. Example

Logical OR: lets say that `1` represents `true` and `0` `false`

```
+---+---+-------+
| p | q | (p|q) |
+---+---+-------+
| 0 | 0 |   0   |
| 0 | 1 |   1   |
| 1 | 0 |   1   |
| 1 | 1 |   1   |
+---+---+-------+
```

Bitwise OR will perform similar operation as boolean but will use corresponding bits

```
decimal   binary
6       = 00110
3       = 00011
OR -------------
          00111
```

> (2) What does this mark exactly do?

`x |= y` is the same as `x = x | y` so it will calculate `x | y` and store it in `x`.

> (3) Are there any other well known signs similar to this?

Yes, every arithmetic, bitwise or bit shift operator can be used this way: `+=` `-=` `*=` `/=` `%=` `&=` `^=` `|=` `<<=` `>>=` `>>>=`

---

Here are some additional informations about usage of `|=` in

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Lets say that we have five properties.

```
Property1 
Property2
Property3
Property4
Property5
```

We can use last five bits of number to represents situations where we have (1) or don't have (0) some property.

```
...00xxxxx
     │││││
     ││││└─ flag for Property1
     │││└── flag for Property2
     ││└─── flag for Property3 
     │└──── flag for Property4
     └───── flag for Property5
```

Now, lets say that we want to use only properties 1, 2 and 4. To do this we have to set bits indexed with 0, 1 and 3 to value 1 like

```
...0001101
     │││││
     ││││└─ (1) has Property1
     │││└── (0) no Property2
     ││└─── (1) has Property3
     │└──── (1) has Property4
     └───── (0) no Property5
```

In other words we have to produce number 13 (= **1***8 + **1***4 + **0***2 + **1***1). We can do this with `|` OR bitwise operator `8|4|1` because

```
   8 = ...001000
   4 = ...000100
   1 = ...000001
OR -------------
  13 = ...001101
```

But to avoid [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518938/what-are-magic-numbers) we can create constants that will represents our properties in bit world. So we can create

```
public class MyProperties {

    //...
    public static final int PROPERTY_1 = 0b0000_0001; // = 1
    public static final int PROPERTY_2 = 0b0000_0010; // = 2
    public static final int PROPERTY_3 = 0b0000_0100; // = 4
    public static final int PROPERTY_4 = 0b0000_1000; // = 8
    public static final int PROPERTY_5 = 0b0001_0000; // = 16
    //...
    //rest of code: methods, constructors, other fields
}
```

and use it later like

```
int context = Properties.PROPERTY_1|Properties.PROPERTY_2|Properties.PROPERTY_4
```

which is more readable than `int context = 8|4|1`.

---

Now if we want to change our context and lets say add `PROPERTY_3` we can use

```
context = context | Properties.PROPERTY_3;
```

or shorter version based on compound assignments operators

```
context |= Properties.PROPERTY_3;
```

which will do this calculations

```
   context    = 000...00001101
   PROPERTY_3 = 000...00000010
OR ------------------------
                000...00001111
```

(main difference between adding value of `PROPERTY_3` to `context` and using bitwise OR `|` is that when `context` will already have `PROPERTY_3` set to `1` then OR will no effect it).

---

Now if you take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL) idea of using single bits as flags for properties was used in `Notification` class, where `FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL` constant has value `16` (`0x010` in hexadecimal, `0b0001_0000` in binary).

Comment: Everything above the first line and after the second is irrelevant fluff.

Comment: @EJP hope it is better now.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far to call it irrelevant, surely they answered many of my rising questions.

Comment: @Campiador It seems that before my edit this answer had really very little with actually asked questions so EJP had good point (so no hard feelings). Since SO is not only for author of question but also for other people that may come here to learn something, answers should be answering question, not only giving additional informations. Now it should be better.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it perform some kind of bit manipulation?

Yes. It "OR"s the right-hand-side operand into the left-hand-side one.

> What does this mark exactly do?

It's an assignment coupled with an OR.

> Are there any other well known signs such as this?

There are plenty: `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, `&=`, and so on. Collectively, they are called *compound assignment operators*. [They are described in section 15.26.2 of the Java Language Specification.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)

Answer (score -1):

It is called bitwise or operator. For example,

```
5     = 0000 0101
2     = 0000 0010
5 | 2 = 0000 0111
      = 14
```

So, this concept is used when a same option can use multiple values.

As an example, consider a variable flags equal to one.

```
int flags = 1;
```

Now, if a flag value of 4 is added to it with bitwise or,

```
flags |= 4;  // 0
```

You can determine whether 4 was applied on flags with the bitwise and.

```
if (flags & 4 == 4)  // returns true
```

If that flag has been applied on the flags, bitwise and returns flag. In this way we can use bitwise and & bitwise or.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is bitwise or logical, depending on the operand types.