# Compiling gcc .o files with g++ .cpp files

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, object-files

I have two files, `print_permu.c` and `gen_permu.cpp`. I wish to compile `print_permu.c` file into an object file and then use the object file to compile `gen_permu.cpp`, which contains a call to a function in `print_permu.c`.

`print_permu.c`

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef char byte;

char *printable=NULL;
size_t pos,size,*char_cnt;

void __print_permu_recurse()
{
        if( pos==size )
        {
                printf("%s\n",printable);
                return;
        }
        byte iter = 25;
        while( iter>=0 )
        {
                if( char_cnt[iter] )
                {
                        printable[pos] = 'a'+iter;
                        --char_cnt[iter];
                        ++pos;
                        __print_permu_recurse();
                        --pos;
                        ++char_cnt[iter];
                }
                --iter;
        }
}

void print_permu(size_t *char_count)
{
        char_cnt = char_count;
        for(pos = 0,size = 0 ; pos<26 ; ++pos)
                size += char_count[pos];

        printable = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(size+1));
        printable[size] = '\0';
        pos = 0;

        __print_permu_recurse();

        free(printable);
}
```

`gen_permu.cpp`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

extern "C"
{
        #include"print_permu.c"
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        string str;
        size_t char_count[26]={},N,iter;

        cout << "string:"; cin >> str;
        N = str.size();

        for(iter=0;iter<N;++iter)
        {
                ++char_count[str[iter]-'a'];
        }

        print_permu(char_count);

        return 0;
}
```

I tried the following commands to compile the code in the said way.

```
$ gcc -c print_permu.c 
$ g++ print_permu.o gen_permu.cpp 
/tmp/ccQxAEea.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `printable'
print_permu.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccQxAEea.o: In function `__print_permu_recurse':
gen_permu.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__print_permu_recurse'
print_permu.o:print_permu.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccQxAEea.o: In function `print_permu':
gen_permu.cpp:(.text+0xe0): multiple definition of `print_permu'
print_permu.o:print_permu.c:(.text+0xe9): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

$ g++ -c print_permu.c 
$ g++ print_permu.o gen_permu.cpp 
/tmp/ccPJA0kU.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `printable'
print_permu.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccPJA0kU.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `pos'
print_permu.o:(.bss+0x8): first defined here
/tmp/ccPJA0kU.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `size'
print_permu.o:(.bss+0x10): first defined here
/tmp/ccPJA0kU.o:(.bss+0x18): multiple definition of `char_cnt'
print_permu.o:(.bss+0x18): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

First, I compiled code using `gcc`, hoping the object file would be compatible when compiling with `g++`. That didn't work. So, I tried to compile both the files using `g++` alone, but to no avail.

How can I compile this code ? 'Am I missing any -options ?

Using gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04), Ubuntu 14.04, x86_64

---

Additionally,

I had initially wanted to declare the `__print_permu_recurse` function inside `print_permu`, which would be allowed in gcc (although not by C Standard). I had followed a similar process. Since that didn't work out, 'changed the code to be compatible even with C++.

Comment: First of all, don't use names with double leading underscore, they are reserved in all scopes. Secondly, don't include the *source* file into another source file. Instead make a *header* file containing the function prototypes of the functions you want to call, and include that.

Comment: Never `#include` a `.c` file, because there is never a reason to do so. It is only good for creating linker errors.

Comment: you need to create a .h file for the prototypes of the functions in the .c file.  That .h should be checking for the cplusplus being defined, and if defined, then use the extern c {...} syntax within the .h file.   #include that .h file in both the .c and the .cpp files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is this construct in `gen_permu.cpp`:

```
extern "C"
{
        #include"print_permu.c"
}
```

You have a source file `print_permu.c`, and a source file `gen_permu.cpp`, which *includes* `print_permu.c`.

When you compile `print_permu.c` to object code, it contains everything from source file `print_permu.c`.

When you compile `gen_permu.cpp` to object code, it contains everything from source file `gen_permu.cpp` **and source file `print_permu.c`**.

When you try to link the two of them together, you get "multiple definition" errors, because everything from `print_permu.c` is *also* defined in `gen_permu.cpp`, and the linker balks at the decision which definition to use.

---

What you probably *intended* to do was to include the *declarations* from `print_permu.c`. This is not done by including the whole source file, but by writing a *header* file `print_permu.h`:

```
// This is a "header guard". It avoids problems if the
// header is included more than once in a translation unit.
// The token used (here: PRINT_PERMU_H) is up to you, but
// should be sufficiently unique. All uppercase is a common
// convention.
#ifndef PRINT_PERMU_H
#define PRINT_PERMU_H

// This makes a C++ compiler aware that function declarations
// refer to *C* code, not C++ code. (The two languages generate
// different linker symbols.) A C compiler will just ignore this
// (as it should, since it does not need any special handling).
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// This just *declares* the *existence* of the function.
// The compiler can use this information (in gen_permu.cpp)
// to create a call-to-placeholder. The linker will then
// turn that into a call-to-function when you link the two
// object files together.
void print_permu(size_t *char_count);

// End of the C++ compatibility construct.    
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

// End of the header guard.
#endif
```

Then, instead of the construct at the top, just write

```
#include "print_permu.h"
```

in your C++ file (or C file, it does not matter thanks to the `#ifdef __cplusplus`).

---

There are various other issues with your source that do not result in immediate failure, but will bring problems if they become coding habit:

[**Reserved identifiers**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/60281).

[**Global variables**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad).

[**Magic numbers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518938/what-are-magic-numbers).

**No comments**, and **assuming ASCII**.

I am pretty sure that your code does some fishy things with characters, assuming an ASCII-7 character set, and will fail if 1) text contains international characters like öéß, or 2) the system in question has non-consecutive encodings for characters (e.g. [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)).

But I got bored trying to figure out what your code is actually intended to do, because there are zero comments in there. (Imagine I had posted that header example without the comments...) So I cannot give you hints on how to improve, just that you should.

I also see a `for` loop without braces (`{}`). ;-)