# Rendering a simple calculation from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm sorry if this looks like a very easy (too easy) question but I'm struggling to find a way into working this out.

I need to calculate the Basal Metabolic Rate according to the data enter into a Body model and render it in my show view. The problem is that I can run the calculation in the view but, of course, this is not a proper way.

```
<%= ((13.397*@user.bodies.last.weight)+(479.9 * @user.bodies.last.height)-(5.677 * @user.bodies.last.age)+(88.362)) * (1 - (@user.bodies.last.fat / 100.00)) %>
```

this code snippet is in a partial that feeds Body#show view. Of course, I want to have this done at the controller level.

So I wrote a method in my bodies_controller that looks like this:

```
# Calculate Basal Metabolic Rate for Males
 def bmr
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @bmr = ((13.397 * @user.bodies.last.weight) + (479.9 * 
         @user.bodies.last.height) - (5.677 * @user.bodies.last.age) + 
         88.362) * (1 - (@user.bodies.last.fat / 100.00))
 end
```

When trying to pull the result of this simple calculation into my Body#show view like this: `<%= @bmr %>` nothing shows. Furthermore typing @bmr into the console returns NIL. How do I feed the Body attributes (Weight, age, height....) into the method?

Sorry if this question sounds stupid but I'm still learning.

Thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can move bmr method to body model as follow

body.rb

```
class Body < ApplicationRecord
 # your other codes 
 def bmr
  ((13.397 * self.weight) + 
    (479.9 * self.height) - 
    (5.677 * self.age) + 88.362) * 
    (1 - (self.fat / 100.00))
 end
end
```

for your note: self is equal to last bodies object

and from your view you can call the result as follow

show.html.erb

```
<%= @user.bodies.last.bmr %>
```

Comment: why User? If we're moving it to a model, it should be in Body.

Comment: I'm considering this @ user = User.find(params[:user_id]) and @ user.bodies inside bmr method, although the controller is Body, but his show method referring to @ user.

Comment: What I mean is, it should be `@user.bodies.last.bmr` (and have `@user.bmr` delegate to `bodies.last`)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev wow thanks, good refactoring catch. let me try to edit it

Comment:  `self` is redundant there, btw.

Comment: Hello widjajayd, Your solution works perfectly as I need it. It also makes sense. Note taken on the meaning of self. I'd like to thank everyone for their contribution :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few pointers I'd give you in solving this more elegantly. Breakdown the problem into more manageable parts, and try to stay away from [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518938/what-are-magic-numbers-in-computer-programming).

```
class Body
  def bmr
    @bmr ||= Bmr.calculate(self)
  end
end
```

(below) obviously, replace `num1` etc. with descriptive names for those numbers so we have an idea of what they mean in this calculation. Also, consider using constants `NUM1` defined at top of class instead of methods.

```
class Bmr
  attr_reader :body
  private :body

  def initialize(body)
    @body = body
  end

  def self.calculate(body)
    new(body).calculate
  end

  def calculate
    ((num1 * body.weight) +
     (num2 * body.height) - 
     (num3 * body.age) +
     (num4) *
     (num5 - (body.fat / 100.00)) 
  end

  def num1
    13.397
  end

  def num2
    479.9
  end

  def num3
    5.677
  end

  def num4
    88.362
  end

  def num5
    1
  end
end
```

On top of that, you could further break the inner calculations down..

```
def calculated_weight
  num1 * body.weight
end

# then

def calculate
  calculated_weight + calculated_height - calculated_age
  # etc
end
```

This gives you a great opportunity to describe the overall calculation and makes it much easier to grasp at a glance, and dig into if necessary.