# How do I remove a trailing ' in Ansible from a string?

Tags: ansible

I am working on an Ansible script that parses a return from the nslookup command. The regex_search pattern  returns a trailing '. I have been trying to eliminate it by using `regex_search('Name:\\s*([\\S]+)\'')` and `regex_search('Name:\\s*([\\S]+)'''')` but to no avail. I also tried using split:

```
          - name: Pull last single quote
            set_fact:
              fqdns: "{{ fqdns | default([]) + [item | split(''')] | first }}"
            loop: "{{ fqdn_step2 }}"
```

I got closer with this piece of code

```
    - name: Rmove the trailing "' and ,"
      set_fact:
        fqdns: "{{ item[:-2] }}"
      loop: "{{ fqdn_step2 }}"
```

But it would return only the last server name.
Here is a minimal repeatable code.

```
---
- name: Test regex expressions
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    short_name:
      - "yourserver1"
      - "yourserver2"
      - "yourserver3"
      - "yourserver4"
      - "yourserver5"

  tasks:
    - name: Query FQDN from short name using nslookup
      command: nslookup "{{ short_name_item }}"
      register: nslookup_results
      ignore_errors: yes
      loop: "{{ short_name }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: short_name_item

    - name: Extract FQDNs from nslookup results
      set_fact:
        fqdn_step1: "{{ fqdn_step1 | default([]) + [item.stdout_lines | regex_search('Name:\\s*([\\S]+)', multiline=true) | default('', true)] }}"
      loop: "{{ nslookup_results.results }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item
      when: item.rc == 0

    - name: Parse the FQDN from extracted string
      set_fact:
              #fqdns: "{{ (fqdns | default([]) + [item | split('\\t')][0] ) }}"
        fqdn_step2: "{{ (fqdn_step2 | default([]) + [item | regex_replace('^Name:\\\\t', '', multiline=true) | default('', true)]) }}"
      loop: "{{ fqdn_step1 }}"
    # The above returns a value like vrtstart001.nadex.co',

    - debug:
        var: fqdn_step2

    - name: Rmove the trailing "' and ,"
      set_fact:
        fqdns: "{{ item[:-2] }}"
      loop: "{{ fqdn_step2 }}"
    - debug:
        var: fqdns
```

I am expecting an FQDN with no trailing '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***An Ansible script that parses a return from the `nslookup` command.***

It seems your apporach could be simplified and minimized a lot.

A [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    short_name:
      - test1
      - test2

  tasks:

  - name: Query FQDN from short name using nslookup
    shell:
      cmd: "nslookup {{ item }} | grep Name"
    loop: "{{ short_name }}"
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.stdout | split('\t') | last }}"
    loop: "{{ result.results }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.stdout }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=Name:  test1.example.com) =>
  msg: test1.example.com
ok: [localhost] => (item=Name:  test2.example.com) =>
  msg: test2.example.com
```

- Since there is a single line output only use `stdout` directly ([Common Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#stdout))
- Split the line on the tab delimiter `\t` ([`split()` filter – split a string into a list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/split_filter.html))
- Use the right side of the result only ([`last` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names))

At this point one is already with

```yaml
test1.example.com
```

and there was no need for removing characters, magic numbers [<sup>1</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/),[<sup>2</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518938/) or regex at all [<sup>3</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706275/6771046),[<sup>4</sup>](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/113243/302852).

**Further Readings**

- [Lookup plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html)
- [`dig` lookup – query DNS using the dnspython library](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/dig_lookup.html)

Comment: Yes that was more elegant. I tried to use the dig module but for some reason dig was hit or miss on returning anything usable in our environment.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by changing the last block to this:

```yaml
    - name: Remove the trailing "' and ,"
      set_fact:
              fqdns: "{{ fqdns | default([]) + [item[:-2]] }}"
      loop: "{{ fqdn_step2 }}"
```

I had tried something similar earlier but I did not place the square brackets around `item[:-2]`