# function calls itself multiple times in javascript when come back to same option in select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, function-call

this is for particular index i.e.(index == 2).
first time when page loads then it will works normally(function calls itself only one time).
when I come back to same option by changing the select dropdown i.e.(index == 2) then function calls itself two times.
again when I come back to same option by changing the select dropdown i.e.(index == 2) then function calls itself three times.
Please help I got stuck in this for about 7 months....

**This is my code..**

```js
function mktchg() {
var x = document.getElementById("mkt__hub");
var i = x.selectedIndex;
// popOver = document.querySelector('.popup__overlay');
const switchMoggle = document.getElementById('mswitch');
const switchMsoggle = document.getElementById('mskwitch');
const mkBa_1 = document.querySelector('.mkba_1');

if (i == 0) {
    document.querySelector('.sea__tbl_mkt').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('fnl_tl').style.display = 'block';
    // document.querySelector('.mkba').style.display = 'none';
    // document.getElementById('exe_mk1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('exe_mk2').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.ist_mk').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('.ist_mk').style.top = '15px';
    document.querySelector('.istr_mkt').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('tx_mk').value = 'Add _ITEM NAME_ item to cart, take a screenshot proving your action.'
    document.getElementById('fnl_in').style.top = '0px';
    document.querySelector('.tgl__area_mkt').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.tgl__pd_mkt').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.istr_sw_mk_1').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.istr_mkt_1').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.mkba_1').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.tgl__mkt').classList.remove('show');
    document.querySelector('.tgl__area_mkt').classList.remove('go');
    document.querySelector('.tgl__pd_mkt').classList.remove('ho');
    document.querySelector('.tgl__ist_area').classList.remove('po');
    switchMoggle.checked = false;
    switchMsoggle.checked = false;
    popOver.style.height = '670px';

} else if (i == 1) {
    document.querySelector('.tgl__mkt').classList.remove('show');
    document.querySelector('.tgl__area_mkt').classList.remove('go');
    document.querySelector('.tgl__pd_mkt').classList.remove('ho');
    document.querySelector('.tgl__ist_area').classList.remove('po');
    document.querySelector('.tgl__area_mkt').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.tgl__pd_mkt').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.sea__tbl_mkt').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.istr_e').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('fnl_tl').style.display = 'block';
    // document.querySelector('.mkba').style.display = 'none';
    // document.getElementById('exe_mk1').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('.istr_sw_mk').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('exe_mk2').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.ist_mk').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('.ist_mk').style.top = '15px';
    document.getElementById('fnl_in').style.top = '0px';
    document.querySelector('.mkba_1').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.istr_mkt').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.istr_sw_mk_1').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.istr_mkt_1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('tx_mk').value = 'Sign in, add _ITEM NAME_ item to your favourite, take a screenshot proving your action.'
    switchMoggle.checked = false;
    switchMsoggle.checked = false;
    popOver.style.height = '670px';
    console.log(i);
} 
else if (i == 2) {
    var dis = document.querySelector('.tgl__mkt');
    function toggleTrea(e){
        debugger
        document.querySelector('.tgl__mkt').classList.toggle('show');
        document.querySelector('.tgl__area_mkt').classList.toggle('go');
        document.querySelector('.tgl__pd_mkt').classList.toggle('ho');
        document.querySelector('.tgl__ist_area').classList.toggle('po');
        console.log('displaying');
        // document.querySelector('.mkba').classList.add('fo');
        popOver.style.height = '1350px';
        if (dis.classList.contains('show')) {
            document.querySelector('.mkba').style.top = '700px';
            // popOver.style.height = '1350px';
        } 
        else {
            document.querySelector('.mkba').style.top = '350px';
            popOver.style.height = '1010px';
        }

    }
    document.getElementById('lit_btn_mkt').addEventListener('click', toggleTrea);
    
    const toggleTreat = () => {
        if (!dis.classList.contains('show')) {
            if (switchMoggle.checked) {
                if (document.querySelector('.mkba').classList.contains('fo')) {
                    document.querySelector('.mkba').classList.remove('fo');
                    document.querySelector('.mkba').classList.add('lo');
                    popOver.style.height = '1350px';
                    console.log('removing fo adding lo');
                }
                document.querySelector('.mkba').classList.add('lo');
                console.log('adding lo');
                popOver.style.height = '1150px';
            } else {
                document.querySelector('.mkba').classList.remove('lo');
                popOver.style.height = '1010px';
                if (document.querySelector('.mkba').classList.contains('ufo')) {
                    document.querySelector('.mkba').classList.remove('ufo');
                }
            }
        } else if (dis.classList.contains('show')) {
            if (switchMoggle.checked) {
                document.querySelector('.mkba').classList.remove('fo');
                document.querySelector('.mkba').classList.add('ufo');
                popOver.style.height = '1650px';
                console.log('1st show then checked');
            } else {
                document.querySelector('.mkba').classList.remove('ufo');
                document.querySelector('.mkba').classList.add('fo');
                popOver.style.height = '1350px';
            }
            popOver.style.height = '1350px';
        }
    }

    switchMoggle.addEventListener('click', toggleTreat);

    document.querySelector('.sea__tbl_mkt').style.display = 'flex';
    document.querySelector('.sea__tbl_mkt').style.top = '-10px';
    document.querySelector('.istr').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.material-icons.cm').style.display = 'none';
    // document.querySelector('.material-icons.mkt').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('lit_btn_cm').style.display = 'none';
    // document.getElementById('lit_btn_mkt').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('fnl_tl').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('fnl_in').style.top = '0px';
    document.querySelector('.istr_sw_mk').style.display = 'flex';
    document.querySelector('.istr_mkt').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('.tgl__area_mkt').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('.tgl__pd_mkt').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('.tgl__ist_area').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('.ist_mk').style.display = 'none';
    // document.getElementById('exe_mk1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('exe_mk2').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.mkba_1').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.istr_sw_mk_1').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.istr_mkt_1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('kemo').value = "Ask a question about the item _ITEM NAME_, the question must be adequate and relevant to the topic. Take 1 or 2 screenshots showing the question and the fact that it is sent."
    switchMsoggle.checked = false;
    console.log(i);
    popOver.style.top = '97%';
    popOver.style.height = '1010px';
} 
else if (i == 3) {
    switchMsoggle.addEventListener('change' , () => {
        if (switchMsoggle.checked) {
            document.querySelector('.mkba_1').style.display = 'block';
            mkBa_1.style.top = '-42px';
            document.querySelector('.istr_sw_mk_1').style.top = '0px';
            document.querySelector('.istr_mkt_1').style.top = '10px';
            popOver.style.height = '830px';
        } else {
            document.querySelector('.mkba_1').style.display = 'none';
            document.querySelector('.istr_sw_mk_1').style.top = '0px';
            document.querySelector('.istr_mkt_1').style.top = '5px';
            popOver.style.height = '680px';
        }
    });
    document.querySelector('.istr_sw_mk').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.istr_mkt').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.istr_sw_mk_1').style.display = 'flex';
    document.querySelector('.istr_mkt_1').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('.istr_sw_mk_1').style.top = '0px';
    document.querySelector('.istr_mkt_1').style.top = '5px';
    document.querySelector('.sea__tbl_mkt').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('fnl_tl').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('fnl_in').style.top = '0px';
    document.querySelector('.ist_mk').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.tgl__area_mkt').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.tgl__pd_mkt').style.display = 'none';
    // document.querySelector('.mkba').style.display = 'none';
    mkBa_1.style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.tgl__mkt').classList.remove('show');
    document.querySelector('.tgl__area_mkt').classList.remove('go');
    document.querySelector('.tgl__pd_mkt').classList.remove('ho');
    document.querySelector('.tgl__ist_area').classList.remove('po');
    // document.getElementById('exe_mk1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('exe_mk2').style.display = 'none';
    switchMoggle.checked = false;
    popOver.style.top = '72%';
    popOver.style.height = '680px';
    console.log(i);
} else {
    document.querySelector('.sea__tbl_mkt').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.tgl__area_mkt').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.tgl__pd_mkt').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.istr_e').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('fnl_tl').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('fnl_in').style.top = '15px';
    document.querySelector('.ist_mk').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('.ist_mk').style.top = '-4px';
    document.querySelector('.istr_sw_mk').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.istr_mkt').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.istr_sw_mk_1').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.istr_mkt_1').style.display = 'none';
    // document.querySelector('.mkba').style.display = 'none';
    // document.getElementById('exe_mk1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('exe_mk2').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('.tgl__mkt').classList.remove('show');
    document.querySelector('.tgl__area_mkt').classList.remove('go');
    document.querySelector('.tgl__pd_mkt').classList.remove('ho');
    document.querySelector('.tgl__ist_area').classList.remove('po');
    switchMoggle.checked = false;
    switchMsoggle.checked = false;
    popOver.style.top = '72%';
    popOver.style.height = '680px';
}
}
```

```html
<select id="mkt__hub" onchange="mktchg()" class="msctab active">
<option value="marketplace_add_to_cart" data-tk="action"> Marketplace: add to cart - $ 4.43 per 1000 </option>
<option value="marketplace_add_to_favorite" data-tk="action"> Marketplace: add to favorites - $ 2.50 per 1000 </option>
<option value="marketplace_ask_question" data-tk="action"> Marketplace: ask a question about an item - $ 12.17 per 1000 </option>
<option value="marketplace_activity_5min" data-tk="action">
    Marketplace: find the item + actions up to 5 minutes - $ 18.62 per 1000
</option>
<option value="marketplace_share_soc" data-tk="action"> Marketplace: share the item on social media - $ 12.17 per 1000 </option>
</select>

<div class="ot_mkt">
  <span id="exe_mk1">Execution:</span>
  <span id="exe_mk2">Reposts:</span>
  <div class="ist_mk">
    <span>Instruction:</span>
    <input class="form-control" id="tx_mk" type="text" value="Add _ITEM NAME_ item to cart, take a screenshot proving your action..">
  </div>
  <div class="tgl__ist_area">
    <div class="istr_sw_mk">
      <label for="language" class="title" id="">Instructions:</label>
      <div class="istr_in">
        <div class="mkoggle-switch">
          <input type="checkbox" id="mswitch">
          <label for="mswitch" class="mlider"></label>
        </div>
        <label for="language" class="title" id="exe_sw_mk">extended instructions:</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="istr_mkt">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Click <b>Like</b> this post, choose emotion __, make a screenshot confirming your action">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mkba">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="istr_sw_mk_1">
    <label for="language" class="title" id="">Instructions:</label>
    <div class="istr_in">
      <div class="mkoggle-switch1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="mskwitch">
        <label for="mskwitch" class="mlider1"></label>
      </div>
      <label for="language" class="title" id="exe_sw_mk_1">extended instructions:</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="istr_mkt_1">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Click <b>Like</b> this post, choose emotion __, make a screenshot confirming your action">
  </div>
  <div class="mkba_1">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="sea__tbl_mkt">
    <div>
      <label>Comment list:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="sea__tbl_second">
      <label>Import:</label>
      <div>
        <span class="material-icons mkt">task</span><small id="lit_btn_mkt">from text</small>
        <span class="material-icons cm">task</span><small id="lit_btn_cm">from text</small>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="material-icons">delete</span><small>clear list</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tgl__area_mkt">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width='12%'>Action</th>
          <th width='12%'>Sex</th>
          <th width='15%'>Subject</th>
          <th width='20%'>Text</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td><button type="button">add</button></td>
          <td>
            <select name="language" id="" class="form-control">
              <option value="day">any</option>
              <option value="week">male</option>
              <option value="month">female</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td width='10%'><input class="form-select" type="text"></td>
          <td><textarea style="min-height: 40px; max-height: 100px;"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
    <small>Records from 0 to 0 from 0 records</small>
  </div>
  <div class="tgl__mkt">
    <label class="key_title">Adding lines from text:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control keywords-from-text-area" rows="10"></textarea>
    <div class="le__btn">
      <div class="key__choose">
        <div class="sea__first">
          <input class="form-select" type="file">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="key__btn">
        <button type="button">add</button>
        <button type="button">replace</button>
        <button type="button">clear</button>
        <button type="button">cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tgl__pd_mkt">
    <label for="language" class="title">Comment language:</label>
    <select name="language" id="" class="form-control">
      <option value="day">Any</option>
      <option value="day">English</option>
      <option value="week">Russian</option>
      <option value="month">spanish</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to the minimum needed to reproduce the issue. Does this really need all those HTML elements? NB: what you describe typically happens when you attach an event listener multiple times. You should avoid attaching event handlers in response to an event. Also, a function that has 200+ lines is just bad design. Split your code into small pieces, small functions. Add *useful* comments to your code. A comment like "initial statement" and "set the flag to true" is not helpful as that is already clear from the code. Instead, add comments that describe what happens on higher levels

Comment: ...Avoid code repetition. There should not be 10 lines that all set some element's `display` to 'none'. Use loops. Avoid setting `style` individually and only use CSS classes for this purpose. Related: avoid [*magic* numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518938/what-are-magic-numbers-in-computer-programming).

Comment: How do you call `mktchg()`?

Comment: You're adding the `toggleTrea` listener twice: Once in the top level if `if(i == 2)` and again in `attachToggleListener()`.

Comment: Every time you call `mktchg()` you'll add more listeners. All the flag variables you use to avoid adding duplicate listeners get reinitialized each time. They probably should be global variables rather than local to the function.

Comment: Where is the `mkt__hub` dropdown in the HTML?

Comment: Even I remove the attachToggleListener still problem exists

Comment: Thank you Barmar....I defined function inside mktchg( ). it should be Global as you say.
thank you once again...you are life saver....